# Jquery get all contents from each DIV's individually

Tags: html, jquery, loops

I've an HTML like below

```
<div id="PanelLevel" class="panel-body">
   <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-3">
            Very Important
            <div id="maindiv1" class="ui-widget-vi">
               <div class='column'>
                  <div class='portlet' >
                     <div class='portlet-header'>Energy_Efficiency</div>
                     <div class='portlet-content'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</div>
                  </div>
                  <div class='portlet' >
                     <div class='portlet-header'>Maintenance_Ease</div>
                     <div class='portlet-content'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</div>
                  </div>
                  <div class='portlet' >
                     <div class='portlet-header'>Cold_Weather_Operation</div>
                     <div class='portlet-content'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-3">
            Important
            <div id="maindiv2" class="ui-widget-i">
               <div class='column'>
                  <div class='portlet'>
                     <div class='portlet-header'>First_Cost</div>
                     <div class='portlet-content'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</div>
                  </div>
                  <div class='portlet'>
                     <div class='portlet-header'>Operating_Cost</div>
                     <div class='portlet-content'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</div>
                  </div>
                  <div class='portlet'>
                     <div class='portlet-header'>Footprint</div>
                     <div class='portlet-content'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</div>
                  </div>
                  <div class='portlet'>
                     <div class='portlet-header'>Height</div>
                     <div class='portlet-content'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</div>
                  </div>
                  <div class='portlet'>
                     <div class='portlet-header'>Sound</div>
                     <div class='portlet-content'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</div>
                  </div>
                  <div class='portlet'>
                     <div class='portlet-header'>Corrosion_Resistance</div>
                     <div class='portlet-content'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-3">
            Somewhat Important
            <div id="maindiv3" class="ui-widget-si">
               <div class='column'>
                  <div class='portlet'>
                     <div class='portlet-header'>Weight</div>
                     <div class='portlet-content'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</div>
                  </div>
                  <div class='portlet'>
                     <div class='portlet-header'>Installation_Ease</div>
                     <div class='portlet-content'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</div>
                  </div>
                  <div class='portlet'>
                     <div class='portlet-header'>Redundancy</div>
                     <div class='portlet-content'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-3">
            Not Important
            <div id="maindiv4" class="ui-widget-ni">
               <div class='column'>
                  <div class='portlet'>
                     <div class='portlet-header'>Indor_Ducted_Installation</div>
                     <div class='portlet-content'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</div>
                  </div>
                  <div class='portlet'>
                     <div class='portlet-header'>Water_Usage</div>
                     <div class='portlet-content'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

My desired output is that I need to extract all 'Portlet-header' class contents only from 4 divs like "maindiv1", "maindiv2", "maindiv3", "maindiv4" as below

"maindiv1" - Energy_Efficiency,Maintenance_Ease, Cold_Weather_Operation

"maindiv2" - First_Cost, Operating_cost, Footprint, Height, Corrosion_Resistance

"maindiv3" - Weight, Installation-Ease, Redundancy

"maindiv4" - Indor_Ducted_Installation, Water_Usage

I've tried the below code but not getting the desired result:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('div').each(function () {
            var i = $(this).attr('id');
            alert(i);
           
      });

 var text = $( '.portlet-header' ).map(function() { 
  return $( this ).text(); 
})
.get()
.join( ',' );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map()` to build an array of the output you require:

```js
let output = $('.col-md-3 > div').map((i, c) => ({
  [c.id]: $(c).find('.portlet-header').map((i, p) => $(p).text()).get()
})).get();

console.log(output);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="PanelLevel" class="panel-body">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        Very Important
        <div id="maindiv1" class="ui-widget-vi">
          <div class='column'>
            <div class='portlet'>
              <div class='portlet-header'>Energy_Efficiency</div>
              <div class='portlet-content'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</div>
            </div>
            <div class='portlet'>
              <div class='portlet-header'>Maintenance_Ease</div>
              <div class='portlet-content'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</div>
            </div>
            <div class='portlet'>
              <div class='portlet-header'>Cold_Weather_Operation</div>
              <div class='portlet-content'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        Important
        <div id="maindiv2" class="ui-widget-i">
          <div class='column'>
            <div class='portlet'>
              <div class='portlet-header'>First_Cost</div>
              <div class='portlet-content'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</div>
            </div>
            <div class='portlet'>
              <div class='portlet-header'>Operating_Cost</div>
              <div class='portlet-content'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</div>
            </div>
            <div class='portlet'>
              <div class='portlet-header'>Footprint</div>
              <div class='portlet-content'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</div>
            </div>
            <div class='portlet'>
              <div class='portlet-header'>Height</div>
              <div class='portlet-content'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</div>
            </div>
            <div class='portlet'>
              <div class='portlet-header'>Sound</div>
              <div class='portlet-content'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</div>
            </div>
            <div class='portlet'>
              <div class='portlet-header'>Corrosion_Resistance</div>
              <div class='portlet-content'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        Somewhat Important
        <div id="maindiv3" class="ui-widget-si">
          <div class='column'>
            <div class='portlet'>
              <div class='portlet-header'>Weight</div>
              <div class='portlet-content'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</div>
            </div>
            <div class='portlet'>
              <div class='portlet-header'>Installation_Ease</div>
              <div class='portlet-content'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</div>
            </div>
            <div class='portlet'>
              <div class='portlet-header'>Redundancy</div>
              <div class='portlet-content'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        Not Important
        <div id="maindiv4" class="ui-widget-ni">
          <div class='column'>
            <div class='portlet'>
              <div class='portlet-header'>Indor_Ducted_Installation</div>
              <div class='portlet-content'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</div>
            </div>
            <div class='portlet'>
              <div class='portlet-header'>Water_Usage</div>
              <div class='portlet-content'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note that the `.col-md-3 > div` isn't a very robust selector, but it will work in the example HTML. I'd suggest adding another specific common class to all those `#maindivN` elements to make the selection of them more accurate and reliable.

Comment: Thanks for your reply I'm not that much knowledge in jquery...in the output I don't want <div class='portlet-content'> content  I need only content from <div class='portlet-header'> from all the 4 maindiv's

Comment: @rajesh the example above doesn't contain the HTML from `.portlet-content`...?

Comment: Thanks a lot Rory...I didnt see correctly....can you share this in JSfiddle so I can understand

Comment: Rory...I'm not getting the output when i use alert(output) instead of console.log(output);

Comment: That's because `alert(output)` coerces the data type of the argument to a string, not an object. Don't use it for debugging

Answer (score 1):

The following may be easier to convert to json format.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var result = {};
    $('[id^=maindiv]').each(function () {
        var key = $(this).attr('id');
        result[key] = $(this).find('.portlet-header').map(function() { 
          return $( this ).text(); 
        })
        .get()
        .join( ',' );           
    });
    console.log(result);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="PanelLevel" class="panel-body">
   <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-3">
            Very Important
            <div id="maindiv1" class="ui-widget-vi">
               <div class='column'>
                  <div class='portlet' >
                     <div class='portlet-header'>Energy_Efficiency</div>
                     <div class='portlet-content'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</div>
                  </div>
                  <div class='portlet' >
                     <div class='portlet-header'>Maintenance_Ease</div>
                     <div class='portlet-content'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</div>
                  </div>
                  <div class='portlet' >
                     <div class='portlet-header'>Cold_Weather_Operation</div>
                     <div class='portlet-content'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-3">
            Important
            <div id="maindiv2" class="ui-widget-i">
               <div class='column'>
                  <div class='portlet'>
                     <div class='portlet-header'>First_Cost</div>
                     <div class='portlet-content'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</div>
                  </div>
                  <div class='portlet'>
                     <div class='portlet-header'>Operating_Cost</div>
                     <div class='portlet-content'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</div>
                  </div>
                  <div class='portlet'>
                     <div class='portlet-header'>Footprint</div>
                     <div class='portlet-content'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</div>
                  </div>
                  <div class='portlet'>
                     <div class='portlet-header'>Height</div>
                     <div class='portlet-content'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</div>
                  </div>
                  <div class='portlet'>
                     <div class='portlet-header'>Sound</div>
                     <div class='portlet-content'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</div>
                  </div>
                  <div class='portlet'>
                     <div class='portlet-header'>Corrosion_Resistance</div>
                     <div class='portlet-content'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-3">
            Somewhat Important
            <div id="maindiv3" class="ui-widget-si">
               <div class='column'>
                  <div class='portlet'>
                     <div class='portlet-header'>Weight</div>
                     <div class='portlet-content'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</div>
                  </div>
                  <div class='portlet'>
                     <div class='portlet-header'>Installation_Ease</div>
                     <div class='portlet-content'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</div>
                  </div>
                  <div class='portlet'>
                     <div class='portlet-header'>Redundancy</div>
                     <div class='portlet-content'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-3">
            Not Important
            <div id="maindiv4" class="ui-widget-ni">
               <div class='column'>
                  <div class='portlet'>
                     <div class='portlet-header'>Indor_Ducted_Installation</div>
                     <div class='portlet-content'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</div>
                  </div>
                  <div class='portlet'>
                     <div class='portlet-header'>Water_Usage</div>
                     <div class='portlet-content'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Miller, for your great support, is it possible to show the output in aspx page instea d of Console.Log....I mean as a JSON format in aspx page itself.

Comment: JSON.stringify(result)